# Making a discord bot in python

Tags: discord.py

Hello there I'm currently making a discord bot in python and i get these errors : [Click to see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAkV8.png)

```
import coloredlogs, logging
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
```

Here is the error when i run python bot.py :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\%user%\Desktop\Omicron-Entetie\bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import coloredlogs, logging
  File "C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\coloredlogs\__init__.py", line 212, in <module>
    from humanfriendly.compat import coerce_string, is_string, on_windows
ImportError: cannot import name 'on_windows' from 'humanfriendly.compat' (C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\humanfriendly\compat.py)
```

Comment: `import coloredlogs` is a module import, and [coloredlogs](https://pypi.org/project/coloredlogs/) is a third-party module. You need to download it, i.e: `pip install coloredlogs`. Also please post the actual error message and not a screenshot. Googling this error would have yielded the same answer as mine.

Comment: i have installed it using ppip install but it won't work any other solutions ?

Comment: Please paste the actual error.

Comment: i added the error

Comment: also does coloredlogs  10.0.1 exist or its outdated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322254/how-to-resolve-python-humanfriendly-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-on-win

Comment: umm i'm not sure i understand .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to check if the add-ons are actually installed. Open the command prompt and type "pip install (addon)"

If that doesn't work and the command prompt gives you an error try with: py -m pip install (whatever you need to install).

If that doesn't work either, make sure you have imported all of the add-ons.